# Ionic swipe to increase issue

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic. I want to create a view that has volume increase decrease like swipes. But here instead of volume i want to increase and decrease numbers upon swiping. I'll post a picture to explain better.Here when i move loan amount swipe to right the amount should increase and left to decrease.I think you get the idea now.Please help.

[image]

Comment: anyone there to help?

Comment: can you share your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not use Range controls? http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#range

Comment: thanks alot!! could you help me with this question too?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932313/how-to-slide-up-a-form-from-bottom-of-the-screen-in-ionic-programming?noredirect=1#comment40596289_25932313

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.12/css/ionic.css">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.12/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <div class="range">
        <input id="rang" type="range" name="volume" oninput="showVal(this.value)" onchange="showVal(this.value)"/>
    </div>
    <span id="valBox"></span>
           <script>
    var val = document.getElementById("rang").value;
    document.getElementById("valBox").innerHTML=val;
    function showVal(newVal){
      document.getElementById("valBox").innerHTML=newVal;
    }
           </script>
```